# What fonts does this article use?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

I wonder what font is used in [this article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/schmidt/schmidt.pdf) ?
I've used [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but can't find the result.
And [Fond Finder](http://www.linotype.com/fontidentifier?start=1) tells me that it's Trump Mediaeval, but they are slightly different.(If you look at m.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The used fonts can be displayed e.g. using `pdffonts`:

```
$ pdffonts schmidt.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
SKGHXE+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            yes yes no      32  0
RGGMAD+CMSS10                        Type 1            yes yes no      36  0
SRMKXJ+CMTT12                        Type 1            yes yes no      40  0
MEAKIS+URWPalladioL-Bold             Type 1            yes yes no      43  0
XMXATW+URWPalladioL-Roma-Slant_167   Type 1            yes yes no      46  0
YMJOFK+URWPalladioL-Ital             Type 1            yes yes no      49  0
YYGKBG+TeXPalladioL-SC               Type 1            yes yes no      52  0
LTFGIL+URWPalladioL-BoldItal         Type 1            yes yes no      62  0
FFQSQZ+CMR12                         Type 1            yes yes no      66  0
WYBEJZ+CMSS12                        Type 1            yes yes no      69  0
VNYREA+PazoMath-Italic               Type 1            yes yes no     103  0
```

It looks to me it uses the `mathpazo` package/font.

Comment: the `pdffonts` command really helps!

Answer (score 10):

It's Palatino, actually URW Palladio; the math fonts are from MathPaZo.

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

Comment: ouch, you beat me by 30 seconds. =)

Comment: @Paulo: I've published a paper for PracTeX. :)

Comment: Me too, but I don't recall the fonts :-)

Comment: @Martin: oh, I owe you guys a drink. =)