# Identifying a symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm looking for the symbols or font which produced these symbols (in math mode):
S and K

[image]

I have no idea which program produced the document in which I found these symbols, so I'm pretty clueless about it. I tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but it brought no results.

Comment: If you have access to the PDF, you can use [`pdffonts`](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/linux/used-fonts-pdf-files/) to extract font information. See [What fonts does this article use?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18624/what-fonts-does-this-article-use) for more information.

Comment: That's a great solution! I'll use it from now on. Luckily my font has already been identified :-)

Comment: For everybody who comes with Google to this question: You might be interested in the more general question [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5645)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can identify the font from some characters using the [WhatTheFont!](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) web service. There you can simply upload an image of the text and the service tries to find the font for you. Sometimes you have to identify the letters in the image manually.

You can then have a look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) if the font is available. The [alphabetic list of all fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) is most useful here.

For your image above I got:

> Brush Script MT
>   from Monotype Imaging Brush Script

The 'SK' from this font is:
http://origin.myfonts.net/114/fs/u/62/70f93c330eef4c8709da2f5d74c97e.gif

On the font catalogue I then found: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/brushscriptx/
which states:

#### Usage

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
```

#### Style examples

```
\bsifamily
```

Because this is not a math font you need, `\bsifamily` does not work in math mode directly. You need to switch to text mode locally, i.e. using `\mbox`. However, I strongly recommend to use `\text` from `amsmath`, so that you get the correct size for sub- and superscripts etc. Finally you should add `\mathord` to get the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}

\newcommand\mathbsi[1]{%
    \mathord{\text{\bsifamily #1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$ \mathbsi{K} = \mathbsi{S} + 1 $

\[ \mathbsi{K} = \mathbsi{S} + 1 \]

$ X_{\mathbsi{K}_{\mathbsi{S}}} = Y^{\mathbsi{S}} $

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 7):

This is a calligraphy font called [*BrushScriptX-Italic*](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/brushscriptx/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\begin{document}
\Huge\bsifamily K \qquad S

\end{document}
```

To use such symbols in Text or math mode use `ensuremath`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=0.80001bp]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage{amsmath,xspace}
\newcommand{\mybpsi}[1]{\text{\bsifamily #1}}
\begin{document}
\Huge\bsifamily K  S

\mybpsi{K} Text $\mybpsi{K}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `\bsifamily` this doesn't work in math mode directly.

Comment: `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`, egreg will love it! ;-) BTW, you can and should write `\documentclass[preview,border=0.80001bp]{standalone}`. `\standaloneconfig` is more for the config file and for settings which can change during the document, i.e. if your have multiple pages (`multi`). You might have meant '0.50001bp`, which is the old default.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Normally I provide examples with `article` Your well class is only for my test-file ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I tested and I need no `xspace`. I am a little bit confused

Comment: Of course! `\xspace` is (scarcely) useful only for commands without arguments.